# JavaScript - Get All parent elements of an element

Tags: javascript

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <div id="child2">
          <div id="child3">
            <div id="child4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

How to get the parent elements i.e if I take target node as `child3` then need to get the parent elements as `child2`, `child1` and parent. Is there any approach to get the parent elements from child in JavaScript. can any one help me on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("child3");

function getParents(elem) {
  var parents = [];
  while(elem.parentNode && elem.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body') {
    elem = elem.parentNode;
    parents.push(elem);
  }
  return parents;
}

console.log(getParents(elem));
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <div id="child2">
          <div id="child3">
            <div id="child4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

```
elem.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body'
```

this will prevent it from adding body and html elements into the parents array

Comment: Thank you Fanjabi it's working fine but i need one more solution is there any way to get the all parent elements without using looping like we can get the children using ele.children .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to check the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```js
var a = document.getElementById("child3");
var arr = [];
for(var n in a){
  a = a.parentNode;
  if(a.nodeName == 'BODY') // return if the element is the body element
    break;
  arr.push(a);
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        <div id="child2">
          <div id="child3">
            <div id="child4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mamun it's working fine but i need one more solution is there any way to get the all parent elements without using looping like we can get the children using a.children .

Comment: @raj, `children` gets the collection of an element's children not parent. As far as I know, there is no way to get all the parents of an element without some kind of loop.....